# Assignement of integer to auto variable generated by boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost

I have a code as below

```
 typedef boost::variant<char, int, double> myvariant;    

 myvariant add(int a, int b)        
 {  
     return (a + b);     
 }  

 int main()    
 {     
     auto i = add(4,5);    
     int x ;    
 }
```

I want to assign `i` to `x`. Any suggestions? If this procedure is wrong then I would be happy to know others.

Comment: Getting the value is covered in the [documentation's tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic).

Comment: Thanks Chris. It works for int and other primitive data types. I was trying with two different Point Clouds of different types, stuck there and was willing to know about the built in datatypes compatability. Thank you !!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve? Do you really need `variant`? If you do, you'll have to get a typed value out of it using `get<>` or `static_visitor`.

Comment: I have to generate point clouds from data. Its uncertain which point cloud would be generated so the return type is unknown. Finally the cloud is stored with auto variable. Now the variable has to be passed to function with PointXYZ cloud so it has to be cast or done something else ..So I thought of using boost::variant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using `boost::variant` better use template?

```
template<typename T>
auto add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

If you want to limit also your template to those 3 types, you can use `static_assert`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I got an error as " more than one instance of overloaded function "add" matches the argument list"  while calling through main.